# Annihilator - Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have already shown that if $N$ is a submodule of $M$, then the annihilator $\mathrm{Ann}(N) =  \{a \in A : as=0, \forall n\in N \}$ is an ideal of $A$. The other part of the question asks to show that if the action is $\bar{a} \cdot n := a \cdot n$, then it makes $N$ an $A/\mathrm{Ann}(N)$-module with a trivial annihilator.

Is it possible to show the second part of the question by not going through the definition of a module directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point you're going to need some definition, that doesn't seem avoidable...

An easy way it to say that a $R$-module structure is a ring morphism $R\to End(N)$ where $End(N)$ is the ring of group endomorphisms of the abelian group $N$.

Then $Ann(N)$ is the kernel of $A\to End(N)$ so you can factor through the quotient to get $A/Ann(N)\to End(N)$ as usual for ring morphisms, which gives you a module structure on $N$, with trivial kernel (ie annihilator).

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how do you define the application  $A\to End(N)$? Your argument seems clever, but some small details missing me to use it.

Comment: As fas as I'm concerned, this is more or less the definition of a module. But you can write it as $a\mapsto (x\mapsto ax)$.

Comment: Ok thank, and what do you mean by "you can factor through the quotient to get $A/Ann(N)\to End(N)$"?

Comment: When you have any ring morphism $f: A\to B$, if $I = \ker(f)$ then $f$ induces an injective morphism $A/I\to B$. That's sort of the whole point of quotients.

Comment: I used the letter $R$ to denote any ring. In particular it works for $A$ and $A/Ann(N)$.